# Allow a Sharepoint group to edit profile pictures of all users in MySite

Tags: user-profile, my-site, groups, picture, edition

I want to create a Sharepoint (or AD) group which could edit profile pictures of all MySite users. I tried to create a Sharepoint group but even with a "total control" (or global control, I don't how it's translate) right the users can't edit any properties of other users. Do you have piece of clue ? Thank you by advance

PS : Sorry for my poor English

Comment: Check this link for a similar issue - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/sharepoint-2010-allowing-users-to-modify-other-users-profile-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Farm admins group can through the SSP/UP Service Application (you didn't say if this was 2007 or 2010). You could probably do something programmatically as well...